# How to use xsl number to count elements

Tags: xslt

Below I am counting elements using `xsl:number`. I would like to count the chapters in order, see below:

XML:

```
<map>
  <part>
   <chapter/>
  </part>
  <chapter/>
  <part>
   <chapter/>
   <chapter/>
  </part>
</map>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
  <xsl:variable name="chapNum">
    <xsl:number count="chapter" format="1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$chapNum"/>
</xsl:template>
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
1
1
2
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I believe I need to use the from attribute but I am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `<xsl:number level="any"/>`